# Dropdown list is not correctly filtering by system type in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is my AngularJS dropdown list not correctly filtering by system type?

Only specific system data should be seen.

```js
$scope.onSystemsLoaded = function (systems) {
            if (!systems) return;

            $scope.systems = angular.copy(systems);

            if (!$scope.systems && $rootScope.selection.selectedSnapshot == null || $rootScope.selection.selectedSnapshot.SnapshotID == '' || $rootScope.selection.selectedSnapshot.SnapshotID == 0) {
                return;
            }

            $rootScope.selection.selectedSystem = CommonService.getDefaultSystem();
            $scope.parentSystems = CommonService.getParentSystems($scope.systems);

            if ($scope.systems.length > 0) {
                // first check system id present in state param, if presnt then take.
                if ($scope.lwTabularViewstate.params.systemID && ($scope.lwTabularViewstate.params.systemID != null || $scope.lwTabularViewstate.params.systemID != '')) {
                    $scope.systems.forEach(function (system) {
                        if (system.SystemId == $scope.lwTabularViewstate.params.systemID)
                            $rootScope.selection.selectedSystem = system;
                    });
                }
            }
            if ($rootScope.selection.selectedSystem.SystemId) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (CommonService.isParentSystem()) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.selectSubSystem();
                        }, 0);
                    } else {
                        if ($rootScope.selection.selectedSystem.SystemId != '') {
                        }
                    }
                }, 0);                
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast('event:updateURLState', {});
        }
```

This is the code. Here systems is having all the systems in the dropdown. But I want to show the systems that are having systemType as 17.

I tried:

```js
$scope.systems = angular.copy(systems.filter(function(system) {
  return system.SystemType === 17;
}));
```

But this is not working. It is not restricting the systemType as 17.